# JS variable scoping

Tags: javascript

```
 var x = 5;

 function a() {

     function b() {
         console.log(x);
     }

     b();
     var x = 6;
 }

 a();
```

In `console.log(x)`, output is `undefined`. But if I change to,

```
 var x = 5;

 function a() {

     function b() {
         console.log(x);
     }
     b();
     x = 6; // remove `var`
 }

 a();
```

then output is 5.

Why this behaviour? Please explain me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example the local variable `x` is hoisted to the top of the scope, i.e. the function where it is declared. It works the same as if it was declared at the top:

```
var x = 5;

 function a() {
     var x;

     function b() {
         console.log(x);
     }

     b();
     x = 6;
 }

 a();
```

As the local variable isn't assigned a value before the function `b` is called, it's contains `undefined`.

Comment: Per [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5) at step *8 c ii*, variables created through a variable declaration are initially assigned a value of *undefined*, so return *undefined* until assigned some other value.